# "На память" или "в память"?

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно: *на память о ком-то* или *в память о ком-то*?

Answer (score 6):

Выбранное выражение чаще всего заключает в себе намек на то, жив тот, о ком помнят (будут помнить), или нет.

**На память о ком-то** (= *чтобы помнить, не забывать*), с кем не скоро предполагается новая встреча, можно (напр. при расставании) сохранить предмет, сувенир. Иногда так можно сказать и об ушедшем человеке, но скорее, в момент появления чего-то нового, что намерены сохранить ("возьму это на память о том-то").

**В память о ком-то** (кого нет в живых) можно провести мероприятие, хранить что-либо и т.п. О живых так не принято говорить.

Comment: Иными словами, "***на** память*" сохряняет припоминаемое явление (человека или событие) в памяти, "***в** память*" - возвращает явление, приносит его как бы на передний план, *напоминает* о нём, так?

Comment: А мне кажется, что выбор предлогов в память/на память можно сравнить с выбором предлогов в сочетаниях положить в стол/на стол. "На память" - то, что часто используется,  меняется, а "в память" - то, что отложено     на длительное хранение в неизменном виде.